NFA with single transition per input and per state
I am new to automata. I am currently designing an NFA over the language {a, b} that should accept strings where the number of as is odd. I have designed an NFA for this, but I think it's kind of like, a DFA. As you can see on this state diagram:

It basically looks like a DFA because it has only one input symbol that goes exactly to one state, as opposed to the description of NFA saying that you can go to multiple states with the same input symbol. In a sense, I feel like my state diagram is being deterministic, like a DFA.
Is my diagram still considered an NFA even if it is kind of deterministic (because the input symbols are exactly mapped to one state)?
I tried searching for other sources about this one, but I haven't found any concrete answers, so I tried my luck here.

As you have observed, your state diagram may look ok, but it is absolutely fine as an NFA. lets see how .
An NFA does not require multiple transitions for the same input from a state—it simply allows them. Any DFA is technically also an NFA because it meets the broader definition of NFAs. The key distinction is that NFAs can have nondeterministic transitions ( ex : multiple or epsilon transitions), but they don nt have to.
In your case, your NFA functions deterministically for all inputs but remains valid as an NFA. If you were to add nondeterministic transitions or epsilon transitions, it would still be an NFA—just with different behavior. So, rest assured that your diagram is correctly categorized. 
For a deeper dive, you might find this resource helpfulhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory

Thank you for this detailed explanation! I really appreciate this one

It is allowed, but not required that an NFA has multiple transitions from the same state and for the same symbol. So every DFA is an NFA. Your diagram is fine.
